# Connecting to openvpn server from linux command line

Tags: linux, networking, debian, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to setup openvpn client on Debian Linux so my traffic goes through he vpn. I have done a lot of Googling and in all the articles I crossed it mentions that I need to copy the certificate and key, as well as the CA certificate, from the server. Below is one of the tutorials

www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/how-to-set-up-a-linux-openvpn-client/1894

Most of the vpn providers just provide me with an ip with userid/pass how would I connect to them without having the certificate and key?

Answer (score 0):

Most of those providers use PPTP (sometimes L2TP), not the OpenVPN protocol, so you need `pppd` instead. See the tutorial for [HideMyAss](http://wiki.hidemyass.com/Tutorials:Connect_PPTP_on_Linux_command_line), for example.